# How can I use if statements for dictionary keys and fill another dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with a structure here:

```
'set1':{ 'status': 1,
            'data': {'1': {'C': ['116.587',
                                 '52.674',
                                 '23.164',
                                 '8.5'],
                            <sth>:...},
                    {'2': {'C': ['11.507',
                                 '50.674',
                                 '23.004',
                                 '8.02'],
                            <sth>:...},
                    {'3': {'C': ['16.587',
                                 '2.674',
                                 '3.164',
                                 '0.5'],
                            <sth>:...} 
                    {'4': {'C': ['0.587',
                                 '1.674',
                                 '3.009',
                                 '0.55'],
                            <sth>:...} 

'set2':{ 'status': 1,
             'data': {'3': {'C': ['116.587',
                                 '52.674',
                                 '23.164',
                                 '8.5'],
                            <sth>:...}
#<goes like this>
```

I need to store the information under C for all channels '1','2','3' and '4' for all the sets, which are more than 100k. But not all the sets have 4 channels but have only '3' and '4', or only '1' and '2' for instance. I am trying to fill non-existing channels with zeros.

I tried using this statement:

```
if( idict[n]["data"][c] ):
```

I think if this is true, e.g. `idict["set1"]["data"]["1"]` is true, it should fill channel '1', else it should fill with '0.000'.

`idict` is the input dict, `odict` is the output dict:

```
for n in idict: #n is the set number
    try:
        if(idict[n]["status"]==1 and idict[n]["data"]):
           #some has status=0 or has no data key. I need to ignore those
            odict[n] = []
            for c in ('1','2','3','4'):
                if( idict[n]["data"][c] ): #THIS IS WHAT I USED FOR THIS ISSUE
                    odict[n].append({
                        c : [
                            str(idict[n]["data"][c]["C"][0]),
                            str(idict[n]["data"][c]["C"][1]),
                            str(idict[n]["data"][c]["C"][2]),
                            str(idict[n]["data"][c]["C"][3])
                        ]
                        #indicies after ["C"] are for the 4 non integer entries 
                    })
                else:
                    odict[n].append({
                        c : ['0.000','0.000','0.000','0.000']
                    })
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

The output should be like

```
'set1':{ 
                   {'1': ['116.587','52.674','23.164','8.5']
                    {'2': ['11.507','50.674','23.004','8.02']
                    {'3': ['16.587','2.674','3.164','0.5']
                    {'4': ['0.587','1.674','3.009','0.55']
        }

'set2':{ 
                     '3': ['116.587','52.674,'23.164','8.5'],
                     '4': [<something similar>]
         }
#<goes like this>
```

but I got empty dictionaries for the sets lacking some of the channels, but the sets with 4 channels are filled.

Comment: First, using such a huge try catch block will not show you the errors. The error actually is due to the same reason as you have mentioned that *some sets are lacking some of the channels*. Instead of fixing up the  channelID. Append the results into the keys available for that set. :) Ill try posting the code.

Comment: before adding this line `if( idict[n]["data"][c] ):` it was doing the same thing. it was filling odict with the sets with 4 channels. but, it doesn't even go to else of this if. incomplete sets are omitted, which I don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. Instead of

`if( idict[n]["data"][c] ):`

I should have used

`if c in idict[str(n)]["data"]:`

Now it works.

Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try the python 'in' keyword to check whether the key is present in the dictionary

ex:

```
if key in idict:
    <rest of the code>
```

Comment: yes, it exist. though, I am getting `u` in front of everything for unicode chars. but I don't think this is the problem because I can fill output dict with no problem and `u`.